# how do you pass parameters into string variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am running a command to add machines to the domain and it all works ok.

I now want to take the values in `$string1` from parameters values, is there a way of doing this?

```
$rg = "resourcegroup"
$machines = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rg

$string1 ='{
  "Name" : "domain.local",
  "User": "domain.local\\domainadmin",
  "Restart" : "true",
  "Options" : "3",
}'

$string2 = '{"Password" : "@@@@@@@@@@@@@B"}'

$machines | ForEach { Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $rg
  -ExtensionType "JSONADDomainExtension" -Name "joindomain"
  -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.0" -VMName $_.Name
  -Location "uk west" -SettingString $string1 -ProtectedSettingString $String2 }
```

Comment: help about_Parameters -Full

Comment: thanks but i need to pass parameters into the $string1 above, I know how to set up parameters etc just need to know how to pass them into the example above

Answer (score 1):

Build a custom object and convert it to JSON. That way you stay clear of any and all escaping issues and since the input is actual PowerShell code, it's trivial to change any part of the object:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  Name = 'domain.local'
  User = 'domain.local\domainadmin'
  Restart = 'true'
  Options = '3'
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

yields the following:

```
{
    "Name":  "domain.local",
    "User":  "domain.local\\domainadmin",
    "Restart":  "true",
    "Options":  "3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick appears to be to escape the curly braces by doubling them.

```
$string1 ='{{
  "Name" : "{0}",
  "User": "{1}",
  "Restart" : "{2}",
  "Options" : "{3}"
}}' -f 'domain.local', 'domain.local\\domainadmin', 'true', '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the strings and parameter variables:

```
param (
    [string]$name
)


$string1 ='{
  "Name" : "' + $name +'",
  "User": "domain.local\\domainadmin",
  "Restart" : "true",
  "Options" : "3",
}'
```